# How to optimize this query in mongodb?

Tags: sql, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

I have a query like below in MongoDB.

```
a = xml_db.find(
    {
       'crawl_id': crawl_id,
       'low_performer': { '$nin': [source] }
    }
).hint('crawl_id_low_performer_index')
print(a.count())
```

Here, `low_performer` is a list of sources, `source` can be numerous (i.e. length of low_performer can be big), upper limit can be 50 for example. But in most cases, it's just 2-3 at max.

`crawl_id_low_performer_index` index looks like this:

```
   'crawl_id_low_performer_index': {'background': True,
                                      'key': [('crawl_id', 1),
                                              ('low_performer', -1)],
                                      'ns': 's.entries',
                                      'v': 2}}
```

Around one million documents should be retrieved by the query.

Now, if I run the above snippet to get the the count of documents, it takes around 100-120 mins. Why is this so slow? How can I improve/ redesign it?

N.B. My end goal is not to count only, rather doing something with the queryset.

Comment: You can use the `explain` on the `find` to generate a _query plan_ and see how the index is used (or not).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to fetch only doc's count use `count` method instead of fetching all documents, and calculate list size

ref - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/

Comment: No I don't want to use count only, I want to use the result to build the xml in the end. This is just to show, I am doing something with the queryset.